# Careers needs a section to communicate information just to potential employers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I've published my CV on Careers, even though I'm not actively looking for a job, because of a family situation in which I would be open to jobs under particular circumstances.  My situation is actually a good thing, but not something that everyone needs to know.  I'd like to be able to communicate this to potential employers, but don't really want this information to appear in my published CV.  I had originally included it in my personal statement, but that gets published publicly.

What I'd like to see is a section available to communicate information only to employers. This section should would contain free form information about the job search process or any special requirements that one might have.

Answer (score 1):

You're able to choose exactly which section of your CV are published publicly via the '[change how it is published](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish)' link at the top of the public view tab. I've used it to make my personal statement private from public viewers.

Is this what you were referring to, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to have a personal statement, it can only be one or the other.  I'd like to be able to have a public personal statement, but a private, job-related message area.