# Need an "Availability" text box on careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'd like to put a statement about my availability into my Careers CV, but I don't want it to be public.  I only want it shown to potential employers who are searching for me so that my current employer won't see it in my public profile.

I can't put it in my personal statement, because I want my personal statement to be visible to the public.

Basically, I'd like to put a brief statement to clarify the "I'm available full-time/part-time/contracting" checkboxes.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/careers-needs-a-section-to-communicate-information-just-to-potential-employers

Answer (score 2):

Or, more broadly, have additional granularity over who gets to see what.  Rather than "visible" have a "visible to employer searches" and a separate "Visible to public" for each box, and have an additional box for availability/location to give employers more information than the current simple setup.

On the other hand this is something that can be discussed in the first round of interviews, so I'm not certain it's necessary.